# Request to update on a Shared Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

We are trying to write some data in a shared data extension through an update request from our client app.
This is the format of the update request that is sent.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ <http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/>" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance>" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema>" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing <http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing>" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd <http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd>" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd <http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd>">
   <soap:Header>
       <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1">
           <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id=<...>">
               <wsse:Username><...></wsse:Username>
               <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText <http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText>"><...></wsse:Password>
           </wsse:UsernameToken>
       </wsse:Security>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
       <UpdateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI <http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI>">
           <Options>
               <SaveOptions>
                   <SaveOption>
                       <PropertyName>*</PropertyName>
                       <SaveAction>UpdateAdd</SaveAction>
                   </SaveOption>
               </SaveOptions>
           </Options>
           <Objects xsi:type="DataExtensionObject">
               <Properties>
                   <Property>
            ...

            </Property>
        </Properties>
        <CustomerKey><data extension key></CustomerKey>
        <Client>
            <ID>1059027</ID>
        </Client>
    </Objects>
    </UpdateRequest>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This does not output any error, leading us to believe the request went without any issues. However, the data extension remains unchanged.

We create this request in a Python framework code and send it through an urllib2.Request object. This process of creating the request and sending it to the Exact Target endpoint has been used for years, and it is now failing for this new shared data extension.

The shared data extension is not empty (it already has some data, hence the usage of an update request instead of a create request).

Is there anything in special one should be careful with because of the data extension being a shared one?

Answer (score 0):

Try Removing Client ID.

```
    <Client>
        <ID>1059027</ID>
    </Client>
```